# Losing characters in TCP Telnet transmission

Tags: c++, windows, telnet, tcpclient

I'm using Winsock to send commands through Telnet ; but for some reason when I try to send a string, a few characters get dropped occasionally. I use `send`:

```
int SendData(const string & text)
{   
send(hSocket,text.c_str(),static_cast<int>(text.size()),0);
Sleep(100);
send(hSocket,"\r",1,0); 
Sleep(100);
return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions?

---

#### Update:

I checked and the error still occurs even if all the characters are sent. So I decided to change the `Send` function so that it sends individual characters and checks if they have been sent:

```
void SafeSend(const string &text)
{       
   char char_text[1];
   for(size_t i = 0; i <text.size(); ++i) 
   {
      char_text[0] = text[i];
      while(send(hSocket,char_text,1,0) != 1);
   }
}
```

Also, it drops characters in a peculiar way ; i.e. in the middle of the sentence. E.g.

```
set variable [fp]exit_flag = true
```

is sent as

```
 ariable [fp]exit_flag = true
```

Or

```
set variable [fp]app_flag = true
```

is sent as

```
setrable [fp]app_flag = true
```

Comment: Why aren't you checking the return value of `send()`?

Comment: From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740149\(v=vs.85\).aspx): "If no error occurs, send returns the total number of bytes sent, *which can be less than the number requested to be sent in the len parameter*." (my emphasis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you absolutely need to check the return value of `send` as it can return after sending only a part of your buffer.

You nearly always want to call `send` in a loop similar to the following (not tested as I don't have a Windows development environment available at the moment):

```
 bool SendString(const std::string& text) {
      int remaining = text.length();
      const char* buf = text.data();
      while (remaining > 0) {
           int sent = send(hSocket, buf, remaining, 0);
           if (sent == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                /* Error occurred check WSAGetLastError() */
                return false;
           }
           remaining -= sent;
           buf += sent;
      }
      return true;
 }
```

Update: 
This is not relevant for the OP, but calls to `recv` should also structured in the same way as above.

To debug the problem further, [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) (or equivalent software) is excellent in tracking down the source of the problem.

[image: Wireshark on Linux]

Filter the packets you want to look at (it has lots of options) and check if they include what you think they include.

Also note that telnet is a protocol with numerous [RFCs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet#Related_RFCs). Most of the time you can get away with just sending raw text, but it's not really guaranteed to work.

You mention that the windows telnet client sends different bytes from you, capture a minimal sequence from both clients and compare them. Use the RFCs to figure out what the other client does different and why. You can use "View -> Packet Bytes" to bring up the data of the packet and can easily inspect and copy/paste the hex dump.

Comment: I have modified my `Send` function but I still have issues

Comment: @Jacob: 1) Your `safeSend` isn't safe as it will go into an infinite loop on an error. 2) You write that all data has been sent, have you verified that with e.g. [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)? 3) I can see in your original example that you send `'\r'`, usually you want to send `"\r\n"` at the end of a line.

Comment: I've identified that it depends on the speed at which I'm sending the characters. If I delay the transmission of each character by an arbitrary amount, it seems to work. Any way, to bypass that (i.e. minimum delay)?

Comment: @Jacob: What are you using to receive the data? Are you sure that is working correctly? `recv` has the be used in the same way as `send` - could sound a lot like the same problem on the receiving end.

Comment: Quite possible. I have a FANUC robot on the other end which runs a Telnet server. I check the state of the received messages by looking at the logs.

Comment: @Jacob: I'm afraid I don't know anything about those. But you can at least decide on which side the problem lies by using Wireshark (link in my second comment). If the packets are sent correctly, the problem is on the receiving side and you patch it by throttling the packets (as it sounds like you're doing). If the packets are sent incorrectly, then edit them into your question and we'll have a look.

Comment: You should integrate that into your final answer ; I used Wireshark as per your recommendation and saw that the text was sent correctly but it was funny. When I typed in the input (using Windows' Telnet client), each character was sent followed by a set of characters. When I use my Telnet library, a string of arbitrary length is sent (even in the latest program where I send a character at a time) followed by the same set of symbols. I really don't know what's going on.